# How to automatically insert new registers from a mysql table to another table on same database?

Tags: mysql, select, insert

I have a website, in this website I use various 3rd party PHP scripts, for example, a blog, and a forum.

Since those scripts were individually made by different developers, they all have different tables, assuming im using a prefix_ on database, for example, `blog_users` and `forum_users` are tables that stores the users details for each script.

`blog_` and `forum_` are prefixes, and both tables are users tables in the same database for each script, and those tables have different structures.

When a user registers in my blog (a new register is inserted in `blog_users` table), how can i automatically insert some information about this new user (like username, password) on the `forum_users` table?

I don't know if this can be done, so I'm just wondering..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a trigger on insert and update operations and from there you should insert/update the information you need in the other table.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a job for database triggers.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html

I've only briefly used triggers in the past, but they work very well.